# operator overloading "+" & "++" in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

public class EncryptVal
{
    private EncryptVal(T value)
        {
        Set( value );
    }

```
    // Encrypt
public bool Set(T value)
{}

// Decrypt & return (T)value;
public T Get()
    {}

public static implicit operator EncryptVal<T>(T value) {
    //shuffle bits
    return new EncryptVal<T>(value);
}

public static implicit operator T(EncryptVal<T> value) {
    //unshuffle bits
    return value.Get(); ///// error ...
}
}
```

i couldnt overload the + operator & ++ operator. How can i do this?

usage:

```
EncryptVal<int> e = 42;
EncryptVal<int> f = 1;
Console.WriteLine("decrypt int count \t= {0:d}", f.Get()); // ok
Console.WriteLine("decrypt int count \t= {0:d}", f); // error
Console.WriteLine("decrypt int count \t= {0:d}", e); //how?
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't have much to do with the question. I neither see an overloading of the + operator nor a usage of it.

Comment: how cna i do this + operator & ++ operator. and T is int, float, double. and Do you'll get value only variable without using the () get?

Answer (score 0):

To overload `+` or `++` you simply add the `+` / `++` operators you want...

```
public static EncryptVal<T> operator ++(EncryptVal<T> value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your implementation here
}
public static EncryptVal<T> operator +(EncryptVal<T> lhs, string rhs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your implementation here
}
public static EncryptVal<T> operator +(EncryptVal<T> lhs, EncryptVal<T> rhs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your implementation here
}
public static EncryptVal<T> operator +(EncryptVal<T> lhs, int rhs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your implementation here
}
public static EncryptVal<T> operator +(bool lhs, EncryptVal<T> rhs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your implementation here
}
```

It is unclear how this relates to the rest of the question, though.
In particular, the `Console.WriteLine` is probably going to want `public override ToString()` more than anything else.